# Switch off cellular network off/on on iPhone (triggered by Bluetooth car kit)

Tags: iphone, bluetooth, sim

I have a car (Audi A7 with MMI & Bluetooth Mobile Telephone interface) and an iPhone with dual SIM card (2nd SIM is plugged into the car). I would like when my car is started (and my 2nd SIM activates), my iPhone's cellular network would be automatically switched off (no radiation in the car anymore). My bluetooth should still stay on (need that to have my contacts synced with my car).
My current day-to-day procedure is the following:

1. when starting the car: manually put the iphone in airplane mode, and then manually switch on bluetooth again (with was also deactivated due to airplane mode).
2. when stopping the car: put manually airplane mode off, and make one outgoing call (e.g. voicemail) to activate my 1st dual-sim card again (otherwise my iPhone does not receive calls i noticed).

Is there is a way to automate this? Or can I configure a kind of iPhone profile which activates/deactivates airplane mode & bluetooth (to have less manual actions).

Comment: I suspect doing this this is not possible with an unjailbroken iPhone, but I am not 100% sure.

Answer (score 1):

On a jailbroken iPhone, with [SBProfiles](http://moreinfo.thebigboss.org/moreinfo/depiction.php?file=sbprofilesDp) and [SBSettings](http://cydia.saurik.com/package/sbsettings) you can utilise profiles to group multiple actions to different situations. The downside is that you have to manually switch the profiles when entering and leaving the car.

1. Make sure you have SBProfiles and SBSettings installed from Cydia.
2. Open SBProfiles. It should have multiple profiles by default; `Default` and `Car` among them. Select `Car` and then `Toggles`. Drag `Airplane` and `Bluetooth` to `On` section. Make sure that `Airplane` is on top of `Bluetooth`, otherwise activation of `Airplane` will turn `Bluetooth` back off.
3. Then, go back to `Car` and select `Done` from the top bar. Select `Default` and then `Toggles`. Drag `Airplane` to `Off` section (and `Bluetooth`, if you don't need it outside the car).
4. Select `Settings` from the bottom tabs. Select `Activation Method(s)` under `Profile Switching`. Here you can select the action(s) that trigger the profile selection to become active. I think it defaults to `Short Hold` of the `Sleep Button`.

Now, when you hold the `Sleep Button` a bit longer than shutting down the screen but not long enough to power off the iPhone, you can select `Car` profile and have cellular turned on but Bluetooth on. Or select `Default` to turn cellular back on. I think you will have to make the call still, unless there's a way to automate it, too.